# Yet another Electrical Sub Panel Bonding for A Condominium

Tags: electrical-panel

At a condominium sub panel, which fed by 3 wires from a main disconnect only, where there is NO main panel dedicated to subject sub panel, is it still allowed to bond ground/neutral bar to the sub panel' s chassis?

Comment: Is the neutral bonded to ground at the disconnect?  If not, then your subpanel is really a main panel, and N and G should be bonded.  Or if this is existing wiring and they're currently bonded, that's grandfathered and still okay.

Comment: Thnx!, I am not sure if the N & G are bonded at the disconnect. This is an older 1985 multi-family building with many condos units, so each unit has it's own disconnect at the main and it's own panel at the unit' s interior .  However, even if it gets a grandfathered pass, will adding an isolated neutral bar to the panel while converting the existing bonded bar to be a ground bar only is advised to make the panel safer!

Comment: If it's a grandfathered installation, you need to keep them bonded unless/until you run a new ground wire back to the disconnect (assuming it's bonded there).  Removing the bond without adding the ground wire will make it much *less* safe, not more.

Comment: What wiring method was used for the feeder to the unit's panel from the meter/disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

### You have a 4-wire feed

You actually do have a separate ground wire, even though you can't see it.  **It's the metal pipe** the wires run in.

Commercial scale buildings like that usually use **conduit** for feeder. And 1985 is before PVC came into vogue.  So almost certainly, this conduit is metal and non-flexible, and is the valid and proper grounding path.  I have four large buildings with not one green or bare wire anywhere in the complex.

### Still unclear on if this is a main or sub panel

You need to check with the condo association about where exactly your neutral-ground bond occurs.  If there is a main breaker down in a utility room somewhere, it is assuredly there.  **But you have to ask**.